# Tomcat's connection pool opens only 20 connections to mysql

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I have a java application with following line in context.xml

```
<Resource 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    maxActive="100" 
    maxIdle="30" 
    initialSize="10" 
    maxWait="7000" 
    name="jdbc/app" 
    password="pass" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://dbhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true" 
    username="user" 
    validationQuery="SELECT 1" 
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="30" 
    logAbandoned="true" 
/>
```

In mysql 'show variables' tells me that max_connections is 151.

Still,

```
use information_schema;
select count(*) from processlist where User = 'user';
```

never shows me more than 20 connections. On tomcat's catalina.out -log I get

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool exhausted
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:103)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
```

What should I check for to find the problem?

Comment: What tomcat version?

Answer (score 1):

And check whether the application is closing connections properly, this is the programmers stuff to do, but still a common error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is a Tomcat problem, check to see if MySQL is limiting the number of connections.

Answer (score 0):

Also check MySQL's max_user_connections variable.